# AWS SES certificate verify failed

Tags: perl, ssl, amazon-web-services, lwp, amazon-ses

I have set up SES successfully on one AWS instance. Now I am trying to use it on a second (not cloned) instance and when I run any of the SES scripts, I get an error:

```
ses-get-stats.pl -k aws-credentials -q
```

I get:

> Can't connect to email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 (certificate verify failed)  LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown  errorerror:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.

Getting the Perl stuff working was a challenge and it is possible I did it differently on the instance. Any place I should be looking to fix this?

When I run:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile .../cacert.pem -connect email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 < /dev/null
```

I get:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com Inc./CN=email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFRDCCBCygAwIBAgIQGcGV1HNHcHHJGun1oi7qbTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
tTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQL
ExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTswOQYDVQQLEzJUZXJtcyBvZiB1c2Ug
YXQgaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL3JwYSAoYykwOTEvMC0GA1UEAxMm
VmVyaVNpZ24gQ2xhc3MgMyBTZWN1cmUgU2VydmVyIENBIC0gRzIwHhcNMTAxMDA4
MDAwMDAwWhcNMTMxMDA3MjM1OTU5WjB2MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMK
V2FzaGluZ3RvbjEQMA4GA1UEBxQHU2VhdHRsZTEYMBYGA1UEChQPQW1hem9uLmNv
bSBJbmMuMSYwJAYDVQQDFB1lbWFpbC51cy1lYXN0LTEuYW1hem9uYXdzLmNvbTCB
nzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAuDbIrCnMbnltwoXJfQrV6UgtYTza
VdjQw+ylHg9pmNRUAeI8kIEkJYK6wIUy8MdJL/NAJdw5H9WFouNyDKi6T2FFGOns
JU0Qf3Cbsf3XymLxPsMPZ0xgqFYS5QfpuXSwjegkaerABHCOdp0bGnYbpXGFfRzv
VYO3ej48ku4XAH0CAwEAAaOCAhAwggIMMD0GA1UdEQQ2MDSCHWVtYWlsLnVzLWVh
c3QtMS5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tghNlbWFpbC5hbWF6b25hd3MuY29tMAkGA1UdEwQC
MAAwCwYDVR0PBAQDAgWgMEUGA1UdHwQ+MDwwOqA4oDaGNGh0dHA6Ly9TVlJTZWN1
cmUtRzItY3JsLnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbS9TVlJTZWN1cmVHMi5jcmwwRAYDVR0gBD0w
OzA5BgtghkgBhvhFAQcXAzAqMCgGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhxodHRwczovL3d3dy52ZXJp
c2lnbi5jb20vcnBhMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAfBgNV
HSMEGDAWgBSl7wsRzsBBA6NKZZBIshzgVy19RzB2BggrBgEFBQcBAQRqMGgwJAYI
KwYBBQUHMAGGGGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLnZlcmlzaWduLmNvbTBABggrBgEFBQcwAoY0
aHR0cDovL1NWUlNlY3VyZS1HMi1haWEudmVyaXNpZ24uY29tL1NWUlNlY3VyZUcy
LmNlcjBuBggrBgEFBQcBDARiMGChXqBcMFowWDBWFglpbWFnZS9naWYwITAfMAcG
BSsOAwIaBBRLa7kolgYMu9BSOJsprEsHiyEFGDAmFiRodHRwOi8vbG9nby52ZXJp
c2lnbi5jb20vdnNsb2dvMS5naWYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAF/FIwfH4c0X
iIPmF6yKfyiAWp+YuxSteMQzlPluZdxRVdXmukJMABKMbKLyroTV8g9G28aMFIIR
YLdCZUHci0mlbeTXmfjpMVIvhWlxYFsE+ZHpC3i77fQMtalv8bmlThjMy9aVMB8x
fUzMSvxRJbSdHIATqHx7CI8ogT5xEYrflbPk0J4ba380Vw3VArmNUKv9pYtgStv8
YikXMK5ufw0sSBFSo2GAumkvH/DJi8d3AnronpD5WWLs24N6uZCvWqWtKK/FiUhV
JUMXrDohrbX+88P5fbVymeOShUiE1bU6sGPbhiHzXH7VvSYHmeaTGUNtjG1aV/py
wHMrnJ7V7Xs=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com Inc./CN=email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
issuer=/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3075 bytes and written 300 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-MD5
Server public key is 1024 bit
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: EA1C64EA86BFBE11BE8395F15DBF6B21228719EB215857257CD71AB2EFC3AE9E
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 9BFE26D5AFD9C1D222DF73A607CD491F617CD87BC7DCD15904954F198692E22ACACBFAA03A6F10B9F87073DA162B4EB3
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1302693748
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
DONE
```

This is the same response as on the instance where ses-get-stats.pl works.

After creating a certificate file as suggested by daxim, running:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile test.cer -connect email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 < /dev/null
```

Returns:

```
    CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com Inc./CN=email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Amazon.com Inc./CN=email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network
```

followed by additional information including the certificate.

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5639803/edit) and provide the output of `openssl s_client -CAfile …/lib/site_perl/5.12.3/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem -connect email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 < /dev/null` where `…/cacert.pem` is the file installed throught the distribution [Mozilla::CA](http://p3rl.org/Mozilla::CA).

Comment: It does not look like you correctly specified the CA file, you can't just follow half of the directions! – Again, in more detail: Install the latest versions of [LWP::Protocol::https](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Protocol::https) and [Mozilla::CA](http://p3rl.org/Mozilla::CA). Find the location of the `cacert.pem` file after installation. It is in one of the `@INC` directories that are mentioned below in the answers section. Run the `openssl` command again, and take care to paste the full path to the `cacert.pem` file after the `-CAfile` parameter.

Comment: Above I elided the full path for brevity. The actual command I used was: `openssl s_client -CAfile /var/ebs0/cpa/private/AmazonSES/Mozilla-CA-20110409/lib/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem -connect email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 < /dev/null`

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, your OpenSSL does not get the intermediate certificate. (Outdated software?)

Install the intermediate certificate with the subject hash 0xeb99629b, available at https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR1513.

You can use it with the `-CAfile` parameter in OpenSSL tools and with the environment variable `HTTPS_CA_FILE` for the Perl HTTPS stack. To use it system-wide, place it in the appropriate ca-certificates directory, e.g. `/etc/ssl/certs`, and [`c_rehash`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/c_rehash/) the directory.

Comment: When I use that certificate file with the OpenSSL tools, it looks like they work (see edited original post). But when I set the HTTPS_CA_FILE environment variable and also add the certificate to /etc/ssl/certs and c_rehash, I get the same error I described above when running ses-get-stats.

Comment: For me an LWP request already works configuration-less with the Mozilla::CA file alone. I can't imagine what's still wrong on your side, so I have no more ideas to tell, sorry. – If you want to compare and equalise the whole software stack between the two systems, use `strace`. It shows you all the library files and opened configuration files involved in an LWP request, this is a relatively short list. Where the versions or contents differ, install the appropriate thing on the system where LWP fails. This way a full clone is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that on the instance which had been working, after I installed the intermediate certificate, it started returning the same error as the non-working instance when I run ses-get-stats. If I can figure out what changed as a result of the certificate installation, that might be a good clue.

Comment: I mean ses-get-stats stopped working after I installed from Mozilla::CA.

Comment: I don't know whether this is an answer or a clue to the answer, but if I rename the directory /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8/LWP then ses-get-stats.pl and the other SES scripts work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=705044

This might have something to do with it.

Comment: Please take a little time to add details of the linked page to your answer - otherwise, if the linked page becomes unavailable in the future your answer will have no further value.

Answer (score 1):

Disable verification of SSL peers and retry.

export PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME=0

Answer (score -3):

try to remove (or rename) this directory:

```
/usr/local/share/perl
```

Comment: After renaming it, when I run ses-get-stats.pl, I get: `Can't locate URI/Escape.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.8.8 /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.8 /usr/share/perl/5.8 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at SES.pm line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at SES.pm line 27.
Compilation failed in require at ./ses-get-stats.pl line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./ses-get-stats.pl line 23.`

Comment: Although renaming the above directory didn't work, renaming the directory /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8/LWP did.