# failed connect or "certificate verify failed" on LWP HTTPS GET

Tags: perl, https, lwp

I posted this problem on Perl Monks yesterday but it worked for everyone who tried it (see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=909968). However, I was using a different URL hoping to simplify the problem.

I'm attempting to connect to api.betfair.com via HTTPS and they have a valid certificate which I've verified in my browser. I am running ubuntu and have 2 versions of Perl. The system one 5.10.0 works and 5.14.0 installed via perlbrew fails. The code is:

```
use LWP::UserAgent; 
use strict;
use warnings;

#$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE} = "/usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org/cacert.org.crt";

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://api.betfair.com');
my $res = $ua->request($req);

print $res->headers_as_string;
print $res->content;
```

Running this under the system Perl 5.10.0 it works fine and I get:

```
Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2011 08:33:04 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"0-1307353787000"
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Jun 2011 09:49:47 GMT
Client-Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2011 08:33:04 GMT
Client-Peer: 84.20.200.10:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=The Sporting Exchange Ltd/OU=IS/OU=Terms of use at www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05/CN=*.betfair.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: RC4-MD5
Set-Cookie: NSC_mc-80-qvcbqj.efgbvmu=ffffffff09208c5545525d5f4f58455e445a4a4229a0;expires=Fri, 17-Jun-2011 20:33:05 GMT;path=/;httponly
```

Running it under Perl 5.14.0 I get:

    <strike>Content-Type: text/plain
    Client-Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2011 08:34:30 GMT
    Client-Warning: Internal response
    Can't connect to api.betfair.com:443</strike>

If I uncomment the setting of HTTPS_CA_FILE and rerun in 5.14.0 I get:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Fri, 17 Jun 2011 08:35:09 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response
Can't connect to api.betfair.com:443 (certificate verify failed)

LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown errorerror:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at /home/martin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.0/lib/site_perl/5.14.0/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.
```

I have Mozilla::CA installed at version 20110409. Mozilla::CA::SSL_ca_file() returns "/home/martin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.0/lib/site_perl/5.14.0/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem" and it exists and is readable by me. I am using LWP 6.02 in Perl 5.14.0 and 5.836 in Perl 5.10.0. I read setting HTTPS_DEBUG=1 should output some debug info but it only does this (for me) when using Perl 5.10.0 and not 5.14.0.

I'm not an SSL guru by any means but I tried some things I found and they just make me more confused:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /home/martin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.0/lib/site_perl/5.14.0/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem < /dev/null
unable to load certificate
10888:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:647:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

openssl s_client -CAfile /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0/Mozilla/CA/cacert.pem -connect api.betfair.com:443 < /dev/null
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=The Sporting Exchange Ltd/OU=IS/OU=Terms of use at www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05/CN=*.betfair.com
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
certificate snipped
sg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=The Sporting Exchange Ltd/OU=IS/OU=Terms of use at www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05/CN=*.betfair.com
issuer=/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)09/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3068 bytes and written 303 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-MD5
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: 81802384A47AF45D2D809A2D10041A4E0B4B4DD821507569216A199ED467B207
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 50DEC11CD2FA57E9BFA95B0156905D2717A79F333A2028FCCCB0F1C32A6B35202A958CEF24D3D2332A00CDCD158B40FB
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1308304989
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
DONE
```

UPDATE: I thought it was because I had PERL_UNICODE=SAL set but unsetting this does not fix the problem.

UPDATE: versions:
Linux ubuntu 10.10 codename maverick
openssl 0.9.80 (I believe up to date on my ubuntu distribution

Comment: I bet you don't have the intermediate certificate like in http://stackoverflow.com/q/5639803#5654982

Comment: For the record, setting the PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME environment variable to 0 [bypasses the certificate verification](https://chrisjean.com/2014/03/17/fix-ssl3-get-server-certificate-certificate-verify-failed-in-bash/). Not recommended, of course, but handy in an emergency.

Comment: Agreed Tim, it should but on my system it did not work and still does not work. Also doing $ua->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0) does not work on my system. I'm still trying to find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.betfair.com:443 < /dev/null > api.betfair.com.pem
$ openssl x509 -in api.betfair.com.pem -issuer_hash
eb99629b
```

Well, whaddayasay, it's the same stupid intermediate certificate 0xeb99629b I've seen missing before with other people, see [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6384217#comment-7480093) for details and how to get it.

Out of curiosity, what version of OpenSSL and ca-certificates are you running? What's your system version/vendor?

Comment: updated op with openssl version and system. Not sure how to find ca-certificates version. Had the same problem with facebook http://www.martin-evans.me.uk/node/95 about a month ago but solved it differently. Thanks daxim - I knew you'd be the one to diagnose this - almost asked you directly.

Comment: openssl s_client -CAfile cert.pm -connect api.betfair.com:443 < /dev/null now works. not got perl working though - still trying.

Comment: HTTPS_CA_FILE=cert.pm perl ca2.pl where ca2.pl is the perl in op fails in same way.

Comment: Download cert you pointed at. sudo cp cert.pm /etc/ssl/certs/Verisign_Class_3_Secure_Server_CA_G2.pem; sudo c_rehash; perl ca2.pl still fails - same problem. symb link in /etc/ssl/certs is 4d241d64.0 -> Verisign_Class_3_Secure_Server_CA_G2.pem

Comment: I did not manage to reproduce your problem in a fresh Ubuntu 10.10 VM, sorry. -- `dpkg --status openssl`  # Version=0.9.8o-1ubuntu4.4  `dpkg --status ca-certificates`  Version=20090814 -- Since you made it work with `s_client`, you can now simply point LWP's SSL stack to the system certs dir: `HTTPS_CA_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs perl...`

Comment: Pointing a system certificates works - thanks and upvoted. This is a really annoying issue though. I wish I can decide where the issue might be so I could report it.

Comment: The problem is many things at once (if nothing else, Perl's culture of wanting to please everyone and PKI through CAs being a total crock) and it can't be solved with a simple report. Visit YAPC::EU, I'll submit a talk.